# BitCoin Linux Application / Proper method to set up

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux

1 - Can I run the BitCoin daemon (before KDM is even started)?

2 - Once I've started KDM, can I then run the GUI which will attach to the daemon, so only one BitCoin 'app' actually working?

3 - Can you get a status report from `bitcoin-cli`, similar to the qt-app (status of catching/caught up with blocks etc...)

Following the [BitCoin Install Guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions) , I ran the qt-app after installtion, it worked fine. I tried the daemon after and got issues with 'no cookies' / problem with rpc authorisation.  I've also stopped the qt-app, then tried the daemon, it worked fine, then tried the qt-app and it complained something was already connected to the default port.

What is the correct order of running it, note the machine is on 24/7 (minus the desktop).

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - Can I run the BitCoin daemon (before KDM is even started)?

You can run the non-graphical bitcoind daemon with or without starting KDM first.

> 2 - Once I've started KDM, can I then run the GUI which will attach to the daemon, so only one BitCoin 'app' actually working?

No. You can stop bitcoind and start Bitcoin-Qt, though.

> 3 - Can you get a status report from `bitcoin-cli`, similar to the qt-app (status of catching/caught up with blocks etc...)

Yes.

```
bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
```

([Source.](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getblockchaininfo))